# Is it possible to change the model of a Backbone.Collection at runtime

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

Is there a clean way to change the model of a Backbone collection at runtime? In other words, I have a collection called `BaseCollection` where by default its model is called `BaseModel`. The model acts as a base class for other models. Say `AModel`, `BModel`, etc.

Now during runtime the collection, based on specific params, needs to understand if it have to call the `parse` method (with a specific override) of the `BaseModel` or one of the `parse` methods used in models that extend from `BaseModel`.

Normally, this could achieved simply extending the collection each time I instantiate it. So, for example, by default is the defined as follow.

```
var BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : BaseModel,

    // other stuff here
});
```

Now if I want to have a collection where `AModel` has to be the `model`

```
BaseCollection.extend( { model: AModel } );
```

Here the complicated stuff. What if the collection does not contain model of the same type. In other words, what if the `BaseCollection` contains `AModel`s, `BModel`s, etc? Note that I need to call the `parse` method for each model, since they differ a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `magic` of creating a collection of different models is by implementing a `model` function.

here is the examples from http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: function(attrs, options) {
    if (condition) {
      return new PublicDocument(attrs, options);
    } else {
      return new PrivateDocument(attrs, options);
    }
  }
});
```

in your case you should use the attributes to decide which model you want to create

Comment: Thanks. +1. I completely missed it from the documentation. If the `condition` is coming from data that returns from a back-end, can I continue to apply this? In other words, where is it possible to find `condition`? From `attrs`, `options` or somewhere else?

Comment: @flexaddicted condition can come from attrs, option, collection state, a flag or any other `synchronous` code you have

Comment: So, for example, within attrs I will find the attributes returned from a request that belongs to a specific model. True?

Comment: @flexaddicted yes, you'll need to find some attribute (from attrs) that distinguish from one Model to another